# Scala how to subscribe to multiple kafka topics

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I would like to convert string arry/list to util.Collection[String] object in scala. I've tried multiple approached but didn't work out.

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer


object KafkaConsumerApp {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val prop:Properties = new Properties()
    prop.put("bootstrap.servers","192.168.1.100:9092,192.168.1.141:9092,192.168.1.113:9092,192.168.1.118:9092")
    prop.put("key.deserializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
    prop.put("value.deserializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")

    val consumer = new KafkaConsumer(prop)

    val topics = List[String] ("my_topic_partition","my_topic_partition")
    val a = Collections.singletonList(topics)

    consumer.subscribe(a)

  }
}
```

consumer.subscribe(a) returning compile time error

```
Error:(24, 14) overloaded method value subscribe with alternatives:
  (x$1: java.util.regex.Pattern)Unit <and>
  (x$1: java.util.Collection[String])Unit
 cannot be applied to (java.util.List[List[String]])
    consumer.subscribe(a)
```

Comment: Post what you have tried, and someone may be able to help you fix it.

Comment: Consumer.subscribe takes list of topics so I don’t see any problem in that please read the documentation of consumer API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to make a `Singleton` `List`.  A `List` is already a `Collection`.

```
val: List[String] topics = List("my_topic_partition","my_topic_partition")
consumer.subscribe(topics)
```

If you need it to be Java just put `.asJava` like `topics.asJava` and use the import `import collection.JavaConverters._`

Comment: I am still getiing same error Error:(21, 14) overloaded method value subscribe with alternatives:
  (x$1: java.util.regex.Pattern)Unit <and>
  (x$1: java.util.Collection[String])Unit
 cannot be applied to (List[String])
    consumer.subscribe(topics)

Comment: ```import collection.JavaConverters._; consumer.subscribe(Seq("topic-1", "topic-2").asJava)```

Comment: Did you try asJava?  `consumer.subscribe(topics.asJava)`